# Java MongoDB ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.convert.CollectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I'm trying to get all documents inside a collection and add them to a `List` as java objects, however when I run `findAll`, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.convert.CollectionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
...
```

And this is the related error log:

```
2016-01-17 20:54:05.956 ERROR 87437 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/convert/CollectionFactory] with root cause
```

Here's the code that results in the exception:

```
public List<TruckEntity> findAll() {

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    MongoOperations mongo = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "trucksDb");

    List<TruckEntity> trucks = mongo.findAll(TruckEntity.class);

    return trucks;
}
```

the line `List<TruckEntity> trucks = mongo.findAll(TruckEntity.class);` is where the exception is thrown.

When I use 
`FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("restaurants").find();`
 I can access the documents using the iterator, so the documents are there as `TruckEntity` class and there's no problem connecting to MongoDB. It's just the conversion is failing because of the missing class.

I have `spring-data-mongodb` and `mongo-java-driver` included in my `pom.xml`. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else experiences the same issue, using a newer version of `spring-data-mongodb` did the trick. For reference I had version `1.7.0.RELEASE` when I was experiencing the issue and updating to `1.8.2.RELEASE` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss `spring-data-commons-core` jar

Comment: I actually tried including it in my pom.xml, but it didn't help. Still, I believe it should be automatically downloaded as it's obviously a dependency.

Comment: @Ayberk, you can visit this page:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/112751-noclassdeffounderror-for-class-entityconverter-when-creating-mongotemplate

Comment: @VinoDang I have come across with that site before, but unfortunately it didn't help either.

Comment: could you post your pom.xml?